# How to open/close android Coordinator layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I need to open/close a CoordinatorLayout in android programmatically, aswell as keep the sliding movement.

When a user clicks on a button the layout should open up between two layouts, then when clicked again should close the coordinatorLayout bringing the other two layouts back together.

toolbar>CoordinatorLayout>recyclerview>

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.coordinate_main);
```

Is there some method I can call with the coordinatorLayout? such as coordinatorLayout.open.

I can't find anything on the web about this, not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: what do you mean by "open"? `CoordinatorLayout` is a normal `ViewGroup`, so do the same as if you wanted to "open" `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or any other `ViewGroup`

Comment: Open as in to show the view between two other layouts, then remove bringing the two layouts to there 'normal' position. Hoped there would be a method call, similar to drawer.open for example. To animate etc the open movement is a complex task?

Comment: i still dont know what you want... you can have <CoordinatorLayout><TextView/></CoordinatorLayout> so what do you want to bring? what two layouts?

Comment: sorry, what I mean is <toolbar><CoordinatorLayout><recycerlview>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect you desire simply enable Layout animations on `<toolbar>` or the surrounding layout and set the visibility of the CoordinatorLayout to View.GONE / View.VISIBLE when due.

Example on a RelativeLayout (should work with any Layout type):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myTopLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/myToggleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="id/myTopLayout"
        android:layout_above="id/myBottomLayout"
        android:visibility="gone">
    ...
    </CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myBottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When myToggleLayout becomes visible, both LinearLayouts should make room in an animation while CoordinatorLayout blends in. Should myToggleLayout be gone, the LinearLayouts should animate in place.

I didn't test this layout in particular, but it should give you the idea. It's even possible to use Custom Transitions on each of the elements, like a resize transition on the LinearLayouts and fade in / fade out on the CoordinatorLayout.

More about Layout animations here: [Android Dev Training - Layout animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-). Good luck with your app!